# Run same VBA code to multiple Sheets in the same workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook has different sheet has same kind of information but different data. But my VBA code works for the Sheet1. How do I run the same code applicable to all of my workbook. My code has "Worksheet_Change" & "Worksheet_SelectionChange" events. I tried to put the code in "ThisWorkBook" but does not work.

Please help

Comment: As the name implies, you will need the code in each worksheet.

Comment: If you have a sub that you want to run in different sheets on the workbook change event, put that sub in a module and call it from each sheet on the appropriate event.

Comment: The same code applicable to each sheets. So how do I do that

Comment: `workbook_sheetchange`.

Comment: Also `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

Comment: [this link is probably going to be handy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) you'll have to change your code to take use the inputs to point at the right sheet